# Silverlight 4 MVVM: Binding SelectedDate in Custom Datetime control results with an error

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

i have a custom datetime control.
When i bind its SelectedDate property it result with the following error:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Set property 'GenericControls.CustomDatePickerControl.SelectedDate' threw an exception. [Line: 44 Position: 131] ---> System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]'.

The code behind:

```
public partial class CustomDatePickerControl : UserControl
{
    #region Properties

    public DateTime? SelectedDate
    {
        get
        {
            return (DateTime?)dtpFromDate.GetValue
                                        (DatePicker.SelectedDateProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            dtpFromDate.SetValue(DatePicker.SelectedDateProperty, value);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Initialization

    public CustomDatePickerControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding("Text");
        binding.Source = txtDate;
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        binding.Converter = (IValueConverter)Application.Current
                             .Resources["StringToDateConverter"];
        dtpFromDate.SetBinding(DatePicker.SelectedDateProperty, binding);            
    }

    #endregion

    #region EventHandlers

    private void txtDate_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDate.Text == "To Date")
        {
            txtDate.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void txtDate_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDate.Text == "")
        {
            txtDate.Text = "From Date";
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtDate" Text="From Date:"  Width="74" Style="{StaticResource CommonTextBox}" Margin="3,0,0,0" LostFocus="txtDate_LostFocus" GotFocus="txtDate_GotFocus" MaxLength="10" />
        <sdk:DatePicker Name="dtpFromDate" Grid.Column="6" Height="23" Width="25" Style="{StaticResource DatePickerStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The view:

The ViewModel:

```
    public DateTime? DiarySelectedDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedDate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedDate == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _selectedDate = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DiarySelectedDate");
        }
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated,
Thanks in advance,
Kruvi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectedDate must be dependency property. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221408%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

**Update**
If you want that will work change declare SelectedDate as dependency property and OnSelectedChanged (invoked on SelectedDate dependency property changed) set NewValue to dtpFromDate control in layout. I'm not sure that it will be good design approach but it solve your problem.

Comment: I don't think dependency properties can be nullable. See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/475639/silverlight-should-support-nullable-dependency-properties

Comment: As I see from exception message kruvi bind DiarySelectedDate from ViewModel to GenericControls.CustomDatePickerControl.SelectedDate property in control. But in CustomDatePickerControl not declared SelectedDate as dependency property. And binding fail.

Answer (score 1):

I notice this is an answered question.

But I would like to notify about [this link](http://mmtoolkitsl.codeplex.com/) to a Silverlight 5 control toolkit I have recently started creating. It contains (among other controls) a DateTimeBox control in which you can handle both date and time within the same control. At this point, it is still under development, but it should be usable for most scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't just do the date binding in XAML?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtDate" Text="From Date:"  Width="74" Style="{StaticResource CommonTextBox}" Margin="3,0,0,0" LostFocus="txtDate_LostFocus" GotFocus="txtDate_GotFocus" MaxLength="10" />
        <sdk:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DiarySelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource myConverterKey}}" Name="dtpFromDate" Grid.Column="6" Height="23" Width="25" Style="{StaticResource DatePickerStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: the reason is I use this control in more than one view/view model, and DiarySelectedDate exists in just of the the view models.